# Number of chess players in a tournament

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In a chess tournament were played 105 games. Each chess player has played with every other player. How many chess players were at the tournament?

I have no clue how to solve this problem. I think this is a combination problem but don't know what formula to apply.

Comment: How many games are played in a tournament with $n$ players? I guess $\binom{n}{2}$. And $\binom{n}{2}=105$ implies $n=15$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio you used the combination formula, right? Could you please explain the algebra how you did it?

Comment: In general, if your approach to math is to ask yourself "what formula should I have to apply here?" you will probably have a hard time. It is more wise to ask yourself "what this problem really wants from me? What do I know? How can I fill the void between the starting point and the arrival?". Doing math is not really about applying formulas. It is dealing with ideas and abstract structures. Formulas are just a by-product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing ingredient is that each player played each other player exactly once.
The problem should have said that.

OK, then if there were $n$ players, how many pairs of players could you make -- because each of those pairs necessitates exactly one game.

The number of pairs for $n$ objects is $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$
Solving 
$$
\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=105\\
n^2 - n - 210 = 0
$$
we get $n=15$ (or $n=-14$, which is obviously not realistic). So there were $15$ players in the tournament.

Comment: This was a question in a university entrance exam, they missed that ingredient in purpose i suppose